# cant seem to get anything but garbage value

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, integer, logic

Code to get the input in sting in form of csv("23,25,27) and then find the highest value of them 27(type int) all. But q seem to return garbage value everytime.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var p=0;`enter code here`
        int q=0,r,s=0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the numbers seperated by comma");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] == ',')
            {
                p = 0;
                s = (s > q) ? s : q;
            }
            //else if (input[i] == ' ')
            //{
            //    p = 0;
            //    continue;
            //}
            else
            {
                q = (p == 1) ? q * 10 + Convert.ToInt32(input[i]) : Convert.ToInt32(input[i]);
                Console.WriteLine(q);
                p = 1;
            }
        
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

OUTPUT:
Enter the numbers seperated by comma
23,27
50
551
50
555
551

Comment: You might want to try [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0)

Comment: `var result = Console.ReadLine()?.Split(',').Max(x => int.Parse(x.Trim()));` However, this will break easily. Buyer beware

Comment: @MichaelRoy yeah i get that it converts the strings into substring. But i wanted to know what's wrong with my logic here. thanks anyway!!

Comment: The integer conversion of character '0' is 48, not 0, because char '0' is at position 48 (hex 0x30) in the ascii table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `p`, `q`, `s`, let's rename those variables to `hasSeenAtLeastOneDigit`, `parsed`, and `currentHighest` respectively, which are much more descriptive names. Also note that `hasSeenAtLeastOneDigit` should be a `bool`, and `r` isn't used anywhere.

```
var hasSeenAtLeastOneDigit = false;
int parsed=0,currentHighest = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter the numbers seperated by comma");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (input[i] == ',')
    {
        hasSeenAtLeastOneDigit = false;
        currentHighest = (currentHighest > parsed) ? currentHighest : parsed;
    }
    else
    {
        parsed = hasSeenAtLeastOneDigit ? parsed * 10 + Convert.ToInt32(input[i]) : Convert.ToInt32(input[i]);
        // Console.WriteLine(parsed);
        hasSeenAtLeastOneDigit = true;
    }

}

Console.WriteLine(currentHighest);
```

You have 2 mistakes here. First, you have accidentally used [this overload of `ToInt32` that takes a `char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Char_), which converts a `char` to its UTF-16 code unit value, not the digit that it represents. You should have used [the overload that takes a `string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_) or [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) if you want to be safer.

```
Convert.ToInt32(input[i].ToString())
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
//         converts to string, so the string overload is used
```

The second mistake is that you are not comparing the last parsed value to `currentHighest`. Consider the case where input is `1,2,3,4`. After the loop ends, `parsed` would be `4` and `currentHighest` would be `3` which is incorrect. This happens because there is no trailing comma at the end to run this line again:

```
currentHighest = (currentHighest > parsed) ? currentHighest : parsed;
```

You can fix this simply by copying and pasting that line at the end of the loop.

```
var hasSeenAtLeastOneDigit=false;
int parsed=0,currentHighest=0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter the numbers seperated by comma");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (input[i] == ',')
    {
        hasSeenAtLeastOneDigit = false;
        currentHighest = (currentHighest > parsed) ? currentHighest : parsed;
    }
    else
    {
        parsed = hasSeenAtLeastOneDigit ? parsed * 10 + Convert.ToInt32(input[i].ToString()) : Convert.ToInt32(input[i].ToString());
        hasSeenAtLeastOneDigit = true;
    }

}
currentHighest = (currentHighest > parsed) ? currentHighest : parsed;
Console.WriteLine(currentHighest);
```

Also note that the entire algorithm can be done with LINQ like this:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var highest = input.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).Max();
Console.WriteLine(highest);
```

Comment: or even `.Select(int.Parse)`

Comment: @CaiusJard Ah, I was trying to do the method group syntax with `Convert.ToInt32` but failed. I give up too quickly! :P

Comment: It sounds like a better strategy than the "beat your head for hours on something that isn't worth getting to work" that I employ too often ! 

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when performing the loop. You need to split input before performing the for loop.

```
// Perform split of the input using ',' as delimiter
var splitstring = input.Split(',');
// iniate max value
var maxval = 0;
// perform foreach loop (similar to for loop but easier to read especially when want to read all the content in an array)
foreach (var x in splitstring)
{
   var y = int.Parse(x);
   if (y > maxval) maxval = y;
}
// Print the final maxval
Console.WriteLine(maxval);
```

There could be syntax errors but the logic should be there.